# How to use Crystal Report in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I have installed Crystal Report by SAP for VS 2010.

Does anybody know any way to how to call Crystal Report from an ASPX page, and how can we work on Crystal Report?

I am very new to it.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No body got time to reply, this is the link,
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Crstalreportusingvs2010.aspx